# Cant' install xrdp on CentOS 7.5

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, remote-desktop, xrdp

`cat /etc/os-release`

```
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

Use these steps to install `xrdp`:

```
yum update -y
yum groupinstall "X Window System" "GNOME Desktop" -y
systemctl set-default graphical.target

yum install epel-release -y
yum install xrdp -y
```

Got error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     | 7.0 kB     00:00
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
epel                                                     | 3.2 kB     00:00
(1/3): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                |  88 kB   00:00
(2/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                              | 928 kB   00:00
(3/3): epel/x86_64/primary                                 | 3.6 MB   00:00
epel                                                                12706/12706
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xrdp.x86_64 1:0.9.8-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xorgxrdp for package: 1:xrdp-0.9.8-1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xorgxrdp.x86_64 0:0.2.8-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1 for package: xorgxrdp-0.2.8-3.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: xorgxrdp-0.2.8-3.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1
           Installed: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.5-5.1.el7_5.0.1.x86_64 (@updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.5-5.1.el7_5.0.1
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.5-5.el7.x86_64 (base)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.5-5.el7
           Available: xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.5-5.1.el7_5.x86_64 (updates)
               xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.19.5-5.1.el7_5
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Don't know how to install it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output from `$ cat /etc/redhat-release` : The `/etc/os-release´ is surplus, and don't show the update level.

Comment: A mirror / package update is currently taking place. Some few mirrors already show `xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1`. ( I can install xrdp + xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.20.1-5.1.el7 , but not run a complete update right now. ( I did an update a few days ago.)) ... Suggestions : Wait a day / some hours ... and do `# yum install xrdp` . ... **Note** : Never use 'yum -y'. May wreck your repo.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thank you very much for your comment. I know the reason now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was hit with the same issue.

You should be able to use: `yum install xrdp --enablerepo=cr` to get around this for now as the xorg-x11-server-Xorg(x86-64) = 1.20.1 packages should be available in the continuous release repo.